# Coloring arks (relationships) in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

Is this possible to color specific ark between two nodes based on the ark's `<id>` property? if so, how can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. However you can color ALL relationship in Neo4j desktop/browser by 1) click on the relationship  2) choose the color below

See example:[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the cypher output to create an svg file in which you can control a variety of parameters including colors. The Neo4j Browser can export a svg (manual process); otherwise you'll need to create the svg in code.

Some 3rd party tools enable this. I'm using GraphRX.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with Neo4j Bloom:
on the right panel, go to the "relationship tab", click on the relation you want to color
then go to the "rule based" tab, select the property that determines the color and set the rule that you want to apply

size and node color can be determined in the same way

[image]